# Meromorphic Function with a Simple Pole at the Origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ be a meromorphic function with a simple pole at the origin. Show that $\dfrac{-f^{'}(z)}{f(z)-z_0} = \dfrac{1}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n(z_0).z^n$ where each $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree
$n+1$. I am getting nowhere with this problem. I tried to work this out using the Taylor series expansion about $0$ and since $z_0$ is arbitrary, this is making the problem even more difficult for me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is $w$ here?. Is it same as $z_0$?

Comment: Sorry!That's a typo.I have edited.

Comment: Something more is wrong, because the new function does not have a pole at 0.

Comment: 1/z is present in the new function

Comment: Not on the left hand side...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the derivative sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the $m$-th derivative of $p_n$ can be expressed as $$p_n^{(m)}(z_0)=\frac{m!}{2 \pi \mathrm{i}}\int_\gamma\frac{-f’(z)}{z^{n+1}(f(z)-z_0)^{m+1}}\mathrm{d}z$$ for some small loop around $z=0$. Now if $m\geq n+2$ then the integrand is holomorphic at $z=0$ and therefore $p_n^{(m)}(z_0)=0$.

Comment: What is p_n and how are you getting this expression?Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Ester These are the Laurent coefficients as in your question (but without the assumption that they are polynomial to start with). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) for the integral expression of Laurent coefficients.

Comment: You mean Laurent series expansion of f?

Comment: No, not of $f$ but of $-f’(z)/(f(z)-z_0)$.

Comment: Ok,let me check this out.If I face further problems,I shall ask you.

Comment: I understand how you are getting p_n(z_0).Can you please explain how are you getting the m-th derivative of p_n at z_0?

Comment: Use Leibniz’ rule to differentiate under the integral and use that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^m}{\mathrm{d}z^m}(a-z)^{-1}=m! \ (a-z)^{-m-1}.$$ (And note that we’re differentiating with respect to $z_0$ in this answer.)

Comment: And finally how are you getting the coeffecient of 1/z to be 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80226/discussion-between-ester-and-wimc).